# Wrap Border around content with WPF

Tags: wpf, border

I have a Grid defined in my WPF application. I want to wrap a Border around the Grid itself. My problem is, the Border is filling the area available to the parent area. Because  this, the Border is huge, but my content is small. My XAML is defined as follows:

```
  <Grid>
    <Border CornerRadius="0,0,2,2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3"  Margin="4">
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Disclaimer}" />
      </Grid>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the border inside your grid.  do it like this `<Border><Grid>...</Grid></Border>`